# Not found error when deleting files in directory, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, I actually wrote a code to remove all files in a directory. However I noticed whenever a file is not found, this error message comes up:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '0.txt'

My workaround was to add an exception to the code but I feel it is more of a problem with my code and that I do not need to add an error exception.

```
try:
    files = os.listdir(filepath)
    for file in files:
        os.remove(file)
except FileNotFoundError as exception_object: 
    print(exception_object)
```

Is it compulsory I must use the Except rule to ignore missing files.

Comment: At first there's an indent missing after for

Comment: @SpghttCd Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 5):

`os.listdir` returns just the file names, not including their path names. You have to include the path when you call `os.remove`.

Change your line of file removal to:

```
os.remove(os.path.join(filepath, file))
```